# Is it ok to use variables at the second level of a multi-dimensional array? Additionally, how do I echo it?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

To describe my question a little more in detail, can I use variables (i.e. `$player1`) at the second level of my multidimentional array?

If so, how do I `echo $player1["name"]` and `$player1["age"]`?

Is it a better practice to use keys in multidimensional arrays (i.e. `"player1" => array();)` or variables (i.e. `$player1 = array();)`?

I am very new to php so your answers are very appreciated. Here is my code:

```
<?php

// list of players

$currentPlayers = array(

    $player1 = array(

        "name" => "Ryan",
        "age" => 26,
        "weight" => 200,

    ),

);



echo $currentPlayers[$player1]["name"];
echo "<br>";
echo $currentPlayers[$player1]["weight"];
```

Comment: It seems that this makes it work:

$player1 => array(...), basically, making the variable a key.

How is the variable accessed outside of the array? for example, echo $player1["name"]; 
does not echo.

Comment: what you are trying to say??

Comment: that alone will not make it work: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hdyUsm

Comment: You have two answer read them. If you set the value for your variable you wont get undefined variable notice. but yah it will produce the result. if your error reporting is off. Thanks

Comment: rodger that Arif, reading them now. I was editing and didn't realize I would get answers so fast, just refreshed my page.

Comment: oh ryan remember in my answer you dont have to declare the $player value in the second line. But its good practice to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you are missing => after `$player1` in your original array. 
Second you are not setting value for your variable `$player1`,

```
<?php
$player1="value1";//declaring the value for $player1 variable
$currentPlayers = array(

    $player1 => array(//replacing = to =>

        "name" => "Ryan",
        "age" => 26,
        "weight" => 200,

    ),

);

echo $currentPlayers[$player1]["name"];
echo "<br>";
echo $currentPlayers[$player1]["weight"];
```

**Output will be**

```
Ryan

200
```

**Explanation**

Lets say you have to player one is ryan second is arif. Both ages and wieght are different. and lets say you have form to get the info.

For example if you enter arif. it will onlcy show information about arif. and if you enter ryan it will oncly show info for ryan.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="player">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php

$currentPlayers = array(

    "ryan" => array(//replacing = to =>

        "name" => "Ryan",
        "age" => 26,
        "weight" => 200,

    ),
    "arif" => array(//replacing = to =>

        "name" => "arif",
        "age" => 16,
        "weight" => 100,
        ),

);

$player1=$_POST['player'];//Declaring the value for player1


echo $currentPlayers[$player1]["name"];
echo "<br>";
echo $currentPlayers[$player1]["weight"];
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I see it works. I'm not sure I understand why a value must be declared first for $player1. Seems like it works without it.

I think a lightbulb just went off in my head though, making $player1 a key (i.e. $player1 => ...) does not assign a value in the same sense as the assignment variable does (i.e. $player1 = ...) which is why my original code did not work. Would you agree with this statement?

Comment: @RyanSherry ryan you dont have to declare the value. it will work with out it. The reason if you declare its good practice. if you give me time i will update my answer why its a good practice. if You are ok with it. please tell me You want me to update my anwer or not two show you why its good practice. Thanks

Comment: @RyanSherry i have updated my answer have a look. Thanks start reading after it says Explanation. Before Explanation is previous answer. Thanks

Comment: @RyanSherry dear if you like the answer please accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you want is:

```
$currentPlayers = array(

    "player1" => array(

        "name" => "Ryan",
        "age" => 26,
        "weight" => 200,

    ),

);

$thisPlayer="player1";
echo $currentPlayers[$thisplayer]["name"];
```

Comment: to expand: firstly the array key (*player1*) has no $, then it needs to be quoted

Answer (score 0):

PHP is very flexible.

A Variable can represent any type of data. A variable is some text that starts with a $. `$myvariable`

Strings are represented by some text within quotes. `"this-is-a-string"`. Numbers have no quotes. `98`.

Associative arrays use "keys" to organize data in the array. The keys can be strings (or numbers).

```
$value = "some value";
$key = 'key2';
$myarray = array("key1"=>$value, $key2=>"Some other value");
```

You can use variables to define either a key or a value when creating an array.

A multidimentional array is simply an array that contains another array.

```
$key = array("second_level_key"=>"Second level value");
$myarray = array("key1"=>$key);
```

Or

```
$array = array(0=>"somevalue", 1=>array("key"=>"value"));
```

Multidimensional arrays can go as deep as you care to make them, and you can use variables at any depth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer with examples, appreciate it